# modify specific line of text while reading from a text file to list

Tags: java, string, list, java-stream, immutability

I have a text file which I read in as a list of strings. After that I try to get one of the strings, modify it and replace it within the list again.

My text file look as follows:

```
a/0/0/0/0
b/0/0/0/0
c/0/0/0/0
d/0/0/0/0
```

The code look as follows:

```
String startOfLine = "b";

List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("pathToMyTextFile.txt"))) {
    lines = stream.toList();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

int index = 0;
int count = 0;
String modifiedString = "";
for (String s:lines) {
    count++;
    if (s.startsWith(startOfLine)){
        String[] splitS = s.split("/");
        int increment = Integer.parseInt(splitS[2]) + 1;
        modifiedString = 
        splitS[0] + "/" + 
        splitS[1] + "/" + 
        increment + "/" + 
        splitS[3] + "/" + 
        splitS[4];
        index = count;
    }
}
lines.set(index, modifiedString);
```

What I've tried to do is to get the string within the list that starts with the letter "b".

Increase the `"0"` after the second `"/"` to `"1"` and then put the string together again to replace the old value within the list.

What happens is that IntelliJ (which I'm using) complains about an immutable object is being modified.
And I'm almost certain that this should be obtainable within the stream itself in the first place, but can't seem to pull it off on my own. Would it be possible to change the value of the line that starts with `b` within the stream before converting the stream to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal operation `toList()` generates an array, which is being transformed into a `List`, and then wrapped by and `UnmodifiableList` generated by the is being with

```
default List<T> toList() {
    return (List<T>) Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(this.toArray())));
}
```

`UnmodifiableList` overrides all mutating behavior, including `set()` method, so that it would throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

The only way you can ensure that collection produced from the stream is modifiable is to make use of `Collectors.toCollection()`:

```
List<String> lines = Collections.emptyList();
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("pathToMyTextFile.txt"))) {
    lines = stream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Alternatively, to process the data right in the Stream you can make use of the Java 16 operation [`mapMulti()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) which allows to incorporate imperative logic into a stream:

```
List<String> lines = Collections.emptyList();
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("pathToMyTextFile.txt"))) {
    lines = processLines(stream, startOfLine);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

```
public static List<String> processLines(Stream<String> lines, String startOfLine) {
    
    return lines
        .<String>mapMulti((line, consumer) -> {
            if (!line.startsWith(startOfLine)) consumer.accept(line);
            else {
                String[] parts = line.split("/");
                parts[2] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(parts[2]) + 1);
                consumer.accept(String.join("/", parts));
            }
        })
        .toList();
}
```

For versions of JDK earlier than 16 the old-good `map()` operation can be used instead of `mupMalti()`, but in such case it would be cleaner to introduce one more delegating method.

***Sidenotes:*** `Files.lines().toList()` *is an equivalent of* [`Files.readAllLines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path)) *which produces a `List` (note that it's either not guaranteed to be modifiable).*

Comment: alright @Alexander Ivanchenko that would make me understand a little bit more what is happening. But would it not be possible, as I know what line I want to change before opening the stream, to change the value when the stream encounters the line that starts with `b`. If I can change the value before converting the stream to a list I would never have to change the list it self?

Comment: @GustavHenriksson *"before opening the stream"* - you mean **in the stream**? Yes, we can. Can you clarify `modifiedString` and `lineToChange` should be probably the same (i.e. `modifiedString` should be used instead of `lineToChange`) ? And your code would change only **one** string (the last one, which starts with something) is it a correct behavior? I.e. only the last sting that has `startOfLine` at the beginning should be modified or all such strings?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the post. Yes modifiedString and lineToChange was ment to be the same value. Yes as I know that the line that starts with "b" is the one to be modifed before reading the file i thought i t would maybe be possible to change the value of that when the stream encounters it

Comment: @GustavHenriksson If there's only one target string, then this logic can be plugged into a stream. Which version of Java you're using?

Comment: Sorry if that was not clear. The string ``startOfLine` has the value `b` in this case. it is instanciated at the top of my example. Here is a example of what I mean to change the value when the stream encounters it.
`try(stream<string> stream......
if line.startswith("b") -> change value
lines = stream.toList()`

If that pseudo code made any sense :)

Comment: java 18. yes there is only one target string and i would know what the string starts with before calling the stream

Comment: @GustavHenriksson One more thing, while constructing the modified string `modifiedString = splitS[0] + splitS[1] + etc.` you're not using the delimiter `"/"`. Is it done intentionally?

Comment: You are so right again Alexander. It should contain the `"/"` as you point out.

stackoverflow asks me to be so kind and not convert the comment section to a chat...

Comment: @GustavHenriksson See the update and try it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249748/discussion-between-alexander-ivanchenko-and-gustav-henriksson).